# Powershell Listview : Add 6 items lists in 6 different columns

Tags: winforms, powershell, listview, multiple-columns, listviewitem

I have an issue with my PS script including a listview.

I need to check the content of 6 directorys and show the content in 6 different columns :

The issue is that i can't get a correct visual, they are all in the same column

Here is my code :

```
$Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "New Test"
$Form.Width = 1550
$Form.Height = 800 

$Listview = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$Listview.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,10)
$Listview.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(550,10)
$Listview.AutoResizeColumns([System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle]::ColumnContent)
$Listview.View = "Details"
$Listview.FullRowSelect = $true
$Listview.GridLines = $true
$Listview.Height = 650
$Listview.Width =1500
$Listview.AllowColumnReorder = $true
$Listview.Sorting = [System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder]::None  

#[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Null',0)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Scripts',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Applications',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Systems',500)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Databases',100)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Datas',150)
[void]$Listview.Columns.Add('Backups',500)

$oButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$oButton.Text = "List"
$oButton.Top = 700
$oButton.Left = 350
$oButton.Width = 150
$oButton.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right 

$a = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts\").Name
$b = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Applications\").Name
$c = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Systems\").Name
$d = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Databases\").Name
$e = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Datas\").Name
$f = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Backups\").Name


$Entry =  New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Null)

foreach($mp in $a){
$Entry1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Scripts)
$Listview.Items.Add($mp)
}

foreach($mp1 in $b){
$Entry2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Applications)
$Listview.Items.Add($Entry2).SubItems.Add($mp1)
}

foreach($mp2 in $c){
$Entry3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Systems)
$Listview.Items.Add($Entry3).SubItems.Add($mp2)
}

foreach($mp3 in $d){
$Entry4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Databases)
$Listview.Items.Add($Entry4).SubItems.Add($mp3)
}

foreach($mp4 in $e){
$Entry5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Datas)
$Listview.Items.Add($Entry5).SubItems.Add($mp4)
}


foreach($mp5 in $f){
$Entry6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.Backup)
$Listview.Items.Add($Entry6).SubItems.Add($mp5)
}

   
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()}) 
  
$Form.controls.add($oButton)
$Form.controls.add($Listview)
  
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

I tried a lot of change but im still blocked
Thanks in advance for you help

Regards

Comment: You're basically trying to do something that Listview isn't designed for. Listview subitems are intended to be related to the first item - yours aren't related in any way. You'd be better to simply use multiple lists.

Comment: Exactly , i was trying to do something touchy i assume it.
I confirm that listview is not completely designed for this but in fact i did it.
I found a workaround by copying items in a csv file, and then import them in the listview
Im now done with this !! 
Thanks for the advice
Best Regards